# div with position absolute crosses hover menu

Tags: html, css

I have two main divs

```
<div1>menu</div1>
<div2>searchbox</div2>
```

I can't display sub menu on hover because of div2 that lies below; `div2=div.searchcontainertop` has position absolute, that div lies on top of hover sub menus, that make impossible to display submenus on hover
i tried, firefox, chrome, opera, IE10 - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lolipop/Uy3X9/)

How to display sub menus?

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.searchcontainermain {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.searchcontainertop {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
.searchcontainerleft {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
    font: 12px/28px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav li:hover, #nav li.jshover {
    background-color: none;
}
#nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 19px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#nav ul {
    border: none;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
}
#nav ul a {
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    width: 114px;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.jshover ul {
    display: block;
}
-->
</style>

<div id="conteiner">
  <div id="main">
    <div id="menu">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="" target="_self">menu1</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="" target="_self">menu2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="" target="_self">submenu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_self">submenu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_self">submenu3</a></li>
            <li><a href="" target="_self">submenu4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="searchcontainermain">
      <div class="searchcontainertop">
        <div class="searchcontainerleft"> some text goes here<br />
          some text goes here<br />
          some text goes here<br />
          some text goes here<br />
          some text goes here<br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: cud you post the HTML itself?

Comment: What browser are you testing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving `.nav ul` a z-index of 1 or greater appeared to work.

And to avoid an apparent issue with local stacking contexts in IE7, I added the following new CSS rule:

```
#menu {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/D6tax/3/) (with background colors to make the layering more obvious). If there are problems running jsfiddle in IE8 and earlier, use this [standalone link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Matt_Coughlin/D6tax/3/show/). Tested in: IE7/8/9, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

Comment: Doh. I was just writing that!

Comment: thank you i tried that the code is working in FF Chrome; the code is not working in IE and Opera

Comment: I see it working fine in IE8/9, but not IE7, so there's probably an issue with local stacking contexts. I'll take another look.

Comment: Try it now. I updated the demo above, and added a link to a standalone version of the demo (if there are problems running it in IE).

Answer (score 0):

give to

```
.searchcontainertop {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: the text of searchcontainertop will not be visible

Comment: Be careful using negative z-index values. In some cases the content may be unclickable.